# What does this sentence in the OpenMPI documentation mean?

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

In the [documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/) of OpenMPI one can read the following sentence in the "When communicator is an Inter-communicator"-section:

> The send buffer argument of the processes in the first group must be consistent with the receive buffer argument of the root process in the second group.

This section only appears in the documentation of non-blocking functions. In my case this is `MPI_Igatherv`.

I have an Inter-communicator connecting two groups. The first group contains only one process, which is a master (distributing and collecting data). The second group contains one or more worker processes (receiving data, doing work and sending results back). All the workers have the same code and the master has its own separate code. The master starts the workers with `MPI_Spawn`.

However I am concerned, I am not using the function call correctly.

As the master tries to receive data, I use the following code:

```cpp
MPI_Igatherv(nullptr, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, recv_buf, sizes, offsets, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ROOT, inter_comm, &mpi_request);
```

The master does not contribute any data, so the send buffer here is a `nullptr` with zero size.

On the other hand, all workers send data like this:

```cpp
MPI_Igatherv(send_buf, size, MPI_DOUBLE, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, inter_comm, &mpi_request);
```

The workers do not receive any data, so the receive buffer is a `nullptr` with no sizes or offsets.

Is this the correct way?

Comment: 1. I have never done this. 2. The MPI standard (which you should be reading, not the OpenMPI docs) says "The send buffer arguments of the processes in group B must be consistent with the receive buffer argument of the root". And this is a remark in the Gather/Gatherv section, there is nothing in the explanation of Igather/Igatherv. 3. The only thing I'd watch out for is how long the `sizes/offsets` arrays are. I suspect that the root does not count in these.

Comment: please post a [mcve], the error might be in the code you did not show.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I don't have an issue, this is more about whether I am using the function correctly or not.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, the standard basically says the same as the documentation. My question is whether I can omit the send buffer specification at the master (receiver) and the receive buffer specification at the workers (senders). With "omit" I mean using `nullptr` and `0` for arrays and size.

Comment: I am pretty sure the standard explicitly states these arguments are ignored, so you will be good :-)